# SQLAlchemy Reflection: How do I query data from specific columns?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy reflection, how do I query for data in specific column?

```
testtable = Table('member', Metadata, autoload=True)

def TestConnection():
    data = None
    loopCounter = 0 
    for data in session.query(testtable).filter_by(is_active=1, is_deleted=0): 
        print(loopCounter + 1, data)
        loopCounter += 1
    if data is None:
        raise Exception ("Could not find any data that matches your query")        
    else:
        print("It worked!")

TestConnection()
```

The above query gives me all the data in all columns in the **members** table. What I want however is to get specific data from columns. E.g. I want to retrieve the **username** and **password** columns but I just can't get the syntax right. Below is what I have so far:

```
def TestConnection():
    loopCounter = 0 
    for password, username in session.query(testtable).filter_by(is_active=1, is_deleted=0):
        print(loopCounter + 1, data)
        loopCounter += 1
    if data is None:
        raise Exception ("Could not find any data that matches your query")        
    else:
        print("It worked!")
```

That fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/workspace/upark/src/monitor.py", line 36, in <module>
TestConnection()
File "/home/workspace/upark/src/monitor.py", line 26, in TestConnection
for password, username in session.query(testtable).filter_by(is_active=1, is_deleted=0):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Am working with Python3.2, SQLAchemy0.8 and mysqlconnector from Oracle.

**EDIT: some slight progress**

Just discovered that I can "filter" out the columns after all results have been returned as follows:

```
def TestConnection():
    data = None
    loopCounter = 0 
    for data in session.query(testtable).filter_by(is_active=1, is_deleted=0): 
        print(loopCounter + 1, data.password, data.username)
        loopCounter += 1
    if data is None:
        raise Exception ("Could not find any data that matches your query")        
    else:
        print("It worked!")
```

That will give:

```
1 pass1 userone
2 pass2 usertwo
```

But as you can see, that is after I've gotten all the columns back. What I want is to fetch data from only the columns I need. E.g. The Members table has got 10 columns. I only need to get data from two of those for efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the columns to select [`session.query(testtable.c.password, testtable.c.username)`] instead of the whole table [`session.query(testtable)`]:

```
def TestConnection():
    data = None
    loopCounter = 0 
    for data in session.query(testtable.c.password, testtable.c.username).filter_by(is_active=1, is_deleted=0): 
        pwd, usr = data
        print(loopCounter + 1, pwd, usr)
        loopCounter += 1
    if data is None:
        raise Exception ("Could not find any data that matches your query")        
    else:
        print("It worked!")
```

Comment: That's not working. It fails with the error `for data in session.query(testtable.password, testtable.username).filter_by(is_active=1, is_deleted=0): 
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'password'` Remember am using reflection so I haven't created "columns" myself in python

Comment: Updated the answer - need to use `testtable.c.column1` instead of `testtable.column1`.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but it now throws a different error: `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/inspection.py", line 74, in inspect type_)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: try `filter` instead of `filter_by` with the qualified column names: `qry = session.query(testtable.c.password, testtable.c.username).filter(testtable.c.is_active==1, testtable.c.is_deleted==0)`

Comment: Its worked finally. Thanks. Two things. One, Why was the `non type` error coming up when you use "filter_by"? Two, do you have a pointer to where I can get a better explanation of SQLAlchemy Reflection? Coz I doubt what I was asking here is in the doc pages for sqlalchemy and if it is, it isn't as straight forward.