# SQLAlchemy Reflection: How do I update data into reflected tables?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy reflection, how do I insert/update data into the tables?

I've just come from understanding how to query specific tables using SQLAlchemy Reflection as [detailed out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223722/sqlalchemy-reflection-how-do-i-query-data-from-specific-columns). Am done manupilating the data and now I want to save into database but I can't figure out how to it. Here is what i've tried so far.

```
class Member(Base):
    __table__ = Table('member', Metadata, autoload=True)
    def set_password(self, member_id, password):
        data = None
        for data in session.add( self.__table__.c.member_id, self.__table__.c.parking_slot_id):            
            self.__table__.c.id = member_id
            self.__table__.c.password = password
            session.flush()
```

That fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/workspace/testmod/src/tester.py", line 44, in <module>
    m.set_password(m, 1, "password")
  File "/home/workspace/testmod/src/tester.py", line 36, in set_password
    for data in session.add(self.__table__.c.id, self.__table__.c.password):            
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1363, in add
    if _warn and self._warn_on_events:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.8.0b2-py3.2.egg/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py", line 1932, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Boolean value of this clause is not defined")
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
```

So, how do we update/insert into reflected tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the way you're using session.add() there is entirely wrong - it has no return value, and accepts mapped objects (such as a Member instance: `m = Member()`) as arguments, not Column objects.  The second argument you're sending is an internal argument not used publicly which is why you're getting an error.

I'd strongly recommend a good read of the [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html) to get a handle on how the Session and the add() method are meant to be used.

The specific usage you're looking for is not necessarily clear, but the calling signature you're giving for `set_password()` indicates you'd want to alter the row with a given member_id to a certain password.   That would imply that it's a lookup method, which would be at the classlevel:

```
class Member(Base):
    __table__ = Table('member', Metadata, autoload=True)

    @classmethod
    def set_password(cls, member_id, password):
        member = session.query(Member).filter_by(member_id=member_id).one()
        member.password = password
        session.flush()

# usage:

Member.set_password(56, "somepassword")
```

If you really just want to emit UPDATE for that one value and no longer have a need for the Member object you just loaded, it can be done more efficiently using a straight update():

```
class Member(Base):
    __table__ = Table('member', Metadata, autoload=True)

    @classmethod
    def set_password(cls, member_id, password):
        session.query(Member).filter_by(member_id=member_id).\
                    update({'password':password}, synchronize_session=False)
```

Comment: Its worked. Thanks for the explanation. To be honest, what you've explained here isn't available in the documentation (unless you prove me wrong). I've gone through the documentation and am pretty comfortable with the standard SQLAlchemy ORM. But SQLAlchemy Reflection feels like a whole new monster. I would never have guessed I needed class methods. Maybe as an advanced Python developer one might figure it out but as a newbie its hard to put two concepts together. Examples like yours here bring people up to speed faster. After here I'll whop up a tutorial for newbies on SQLAlchemy Reflection

Comment: the classmethod thing is more of an OO programming thing, I was referring to how Session.add() works.  I know you can find that in the docs !   the session works the same way regardless of how you got your Table objects.